How to retrieve values from asynchronous event handlers and AJAX calls?
I'm trying to grab values from event handlers and asynchronous functions like AJAX calls and store them in a variable. Here's my current code:
let result = ""; 

someInput.onchange = () => { 
  result = someInput.value; 
};

fetch("someapi")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    result = data.foo;
  });

some.api.call(42, (data) => { 
  result = data.bar; 
});

someDiv.textContent = result; 

The problem is that nothing shows up in someDiv. I understand that JavaScript is asynchronous, but I'm not sure how to properly handle the values I get back from these functions.
How can I get the values from event handlers and AJAX calls into my result variable?
Or, how can I wait for these asynchronous functions to finish before setting the content of someDiv?
I've tried a few different things, but nothing seems to work.
